# Reading XML file's content from AWS S3 bucket using boto3 library

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-glue

I am trying to read the content of an XML file for parsing using the BOTO3 library and getting below error while doing that.
I am using the below python code.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket_name')
key = 'audit'

for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix="Folder/XML.xml"):
    key = obj.key
    body = obj.get()['Body'].read()
    parsed_xml = et.fromstring(body)
```

I am getting below error while printing parsed_xml variable or body.

**---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 parsed
NameError: name 'parsed_xml' is not defined**
If I will print body in the above code, it should be shown in XML tags.

Comment: Are you printing  `parsed` instead of `parsed_xml`

Comment: @venky__ Edited.   In my original code, it is with the name parsed only.

I am trying to print body and parsed_xml also, but getting an error that it is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define 'parsed_xml' outside the 'for' sentence.

```
parsed_xml = ''
```